# Como passar o valor do sg.Input para uma variavel em outra parte do codigo?

Tags: python, sqlite, variáveis, input

Estou fazendo um programa para apresentar no projeto da faculdade, mas estou fazendo pelo metodo de janela pelo pySimpleGUI, queria que quando a pessoa digitasse no sg.Input uma quantidade, essa quantidade fosse calculada vezes o preço do produto que estaria na tabela, tentei das formas que eu sabia so que não funcionou, desidi por procurar fazer por banco de dados so que tambem nao achei uma forma de levar os dados para o banco e depois puxar de volta pro programa, alguem poderia me ajudar a resolver se der por favor.

codigo:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import sqlite3 

banco =sqlite3.connect("variaveis.db")

#janela inicial
def janela_inicial():
    sg.theme("Reddit")
    layout =[
        [sg.Button("Comprar")],
        [sg.Button("Informações")],
        [sg.Button("Sair")]
    ]
    return sg.Window("Inicio", layout= layout, finalize= True)

#janela de compras
def janela_compras():
    sg.theme("Reddit")
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Produtos:"), sg.Text("            Quantidade:")],
        [sg.Text("[1] - Maçã: R$0,75"), sg.Input(key= 'quantM', size= (20,1))],
        [sg.Text("[2] - Feijão: R$5,00"), sg.Input(key= 'quantF', size= (20,1))],
        [sg.Text("[3] - Arroz: R$3,00"), sg.Input(key= 'quantA', size= (20,1))],
        [sg.Button("Voltar"), sg.Button("Finalizar compra")]
    
    ]
    return sg.Window("Compras", layout= layout, finalize= True)

#janela de conta
def janela_conta():
    sg.theme("Reddit")
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("===================")],
        [sg.Text("               Nota")],
        [sg.Text("===================")],
        [sg.Text("Produto:"), sg.Text("   Total:")],
        [sg.Text("Maçã: R$")],
        [sg.Text("--------------------------------------")],
        [sg.Text("Feijão: R$")],
        [sg.Text("--------------------------------------")],
        [sg.Text("Arroz: R$")],
        [sg.Text("--------------------------------------")],
        [sg.Text("Total: R$")],
        [sg.Button("Voltar"), sg.Button("Finalizar compra")]
    ]
    return sg.Window("Nota", layout= layout, finalize= True)

def janela_informacoes():
    sg.theme("Reddit")
    layout = [
    [sg.Text("Nenhuma informação no momento!")],
    [sg.Button('Voltar')]
    ]
    return sg.Window("Nota", layout= layout, finalize= True)

#janelas iniciais
janela1, janela2, janela3, janela4 = janela_inicial(), None, None, None

#loop leitura de eventos
while True:
    window, event, value = sg.read_all_windows()

    #quando  a janela for fechada
    if window == janela1 and event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break 
    elif window == janela2 and event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif window == janela3 and event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif window == janela4 and event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break 

    #proxima janela compras
    elif window == janela1 and event == 'Comprar':
        janela2 = janela_compras()
        janela1.hide()

    #proxima janela informações
    elif window == janela1 and event == 'Informações':
        janela4 = janela_informacoes()
        janela1.hide()

    #proxiam janela conta
    elif window == janela2 and event == 'Finalizar compra':
        janela3 = janela_conta()
        janela2.hide()

    #voltar janela comprar para inicial
    if window == janela2 and event == "Voltar":
        janela2.hide()
        janela1.un_hide()

    #voltar janela informaçoes para inicial
    if window == janela4 and event == "Voltar":
        janela4.hide()
        janela1.un_hide()

    #janela fechar programa
    if window == janela1 and event == "Sair":
        break

#voltar janela conta para comprar
if window == janela3 and event == "Voltar":
    janela3.hide()
    janela2.un_hide()

#janela pop-up
elif window == janela3 and event == 'Finalizar compra':
    sg.popup("Obrigado pela compra e volte sempre!")
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Ficou um pouco gambiarrento, mas deu certo.

Primeiro: Esquece o SQL. Pra esse código ai, é um overkill. Mas se vc pretende expandir essa aplicação, o SQL pode ser uma boa ideia.

Segundo: Faça as seguintes alterações na janela de conta:

```
#janela de conta
def janela_conta():
    sg.theme("Reddit")
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("===================")],
        [sg.Text("               Nota")],
        [sg.Text("===================")],
        [sg.Text("Produto:"), sg.Text("   Total:")],
        [sg.Text(key= "TvalM", size=(20,1))],
        [sg.Text("--------------------------------------")],
        [sg.Text(key= "TvalF", size=(20,1))],
        [sg.Text("--------------------------------------")],
        [sg.Text(key= "TvalA", size=(20,1))],
        [sg.Text("--------------------------------------")],
        [sg.Text(key= "TvalTot", size=(20,1))],
        [sg.Button("Voltar"), sg.Button("Finalizar compra")]
    ]
    return sg.Window("Nota", layout= layout, finalize= True)
```

Terceiro: faça a seguinte alteração `while`:

```
    #proxima janela conta
    elif window == janela2 and event == 'Finalizar compra':
        janela3 = janela_conta()
        
        valM = int(value['quantM'])*0.75
        valA = int(value['quantA'])*3.00
        valF = int(value['quantF'])*5.00
        valTot = valM + valA + valF
        
        janela3["TvalM"].update(value['quantM'] + ' * R$ 0,75 = %.2f' %(valM))
        janela3['TvalF'].update(value['quantF'] + ' * R$ 5,00 = %.2f' %(valF))
        janela3['TvalA'].update(value['quantA'] + ' * R$ 3,00 = %.2f' %(valA))
        janela3['TvalTot'].update('Total = %.2f' %(valTot))
        janela2.hide()
```

Ai já vai funcionar a questão de você usar os valores das variáveis do `sg.input`. Cabe a você agora organizar o código da forma que preferir.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda cara !!